# stacking 2 column vectors

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays

```
a.shape = (100,)
b.shape = (50,)
np.vstack((a,b))

ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

vstack is supposed to stack the arrays in rows. I have 2 column vectors which should work.

But when i try with

```
np.hstack((a,b))
```

it gives me `(150,)` which is what i want. Why is this the case? Isnt vstack supposed to be stack in rows?

Comment: can you please share the definition of numpy arrays a & b ?

Comment: Read about `numpy.newaxis` or the use of `None` in indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`column vectors` is not a useful descriptor in for these 1d arrays.

```
In [1668]: x=np.arange(10)
In [1669]: x.shape
Out[1669]: (10,)
```

The default display is as row (split into lines if long enough)

```
In [1670]: x
Out[1670]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I have to add an extra dimension to make it display as a column:

```
In [1671]: x[:,None]
Out[1671]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
        ...
       [8],
       [9]])
In [1672]: _.shape
Out[1672]: (10, 1)
```

Plain concatenate joins this shape end-to-end

```
In [1673]: np.concatenate((x,x)).shape
Out[1673]: (20,)
```

We can add the `axis=0` or `axis=-1` or use `hstack` to do the same.

`vstack` joins them 'vertically', but first it turns each one into 2d, e.g. (1,10), so the result is (2,10):

```
In [1674]: np.vstack((x,x)).shape
Out[1674]: (2, 10)
```

That's what numpy users mean by stacking rows.

`vstack` works for my example because the 2 arrays have the same size.  In your's they differ.  It's trying to concatenate a (1,100) to a (1,50) on the 1st axis.

Answer (score 3):

Rows and columns don't exactly make sense when you have one-dimensional arrays, only with multidimensional arrays. This is also exlicitly mentioned in the docs for [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy-vstack):

> Equivalent to np.concatenate(tup, axis=0) **if tup contains arrays that are at least 2-dimensional**.

For 1D arrays you could simply use `np.concatenate`:

```
>>> np.concatenate([np.ones(10), np.ones(5)])
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1.])
```

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning the new(-ish) generic `numpy.stack` function that is now available.

Comment: @PaulH But stacking with `np.stack` requires them to have overall equal shapes. The OP stated that "_[`np.hstack`] gives me (150,) which is what i want._". Did I completly misunderstand what he has been asking?

Comment: No, you didn't. I misunderstood the purpose of `stack`. Sorry for the noise.